# Django. ImportError: No module named unicodedata

Tags: python, django, windows, pycharm

Today I was tried start my python web project by `python manage.py runserver`
and get error:

```
ImportError: No module named unicodedata
```

When I tried to find solution of my problem I get some another errors.

I try `pip install unicodedata` and get

```
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'
```

Then I try `python -m pip install unicodedata`

```
LookupError: unknown encoding: idna
```

So I try `>>>import encodings.idna` but have error again:

```
ImportError: No module named unicodedata
```

My python: 2.7.12.
I tried to reinstall it, but it's did not help me

So, this is my problem.

Comment: try installing docutils.

Comment: It gives me `LookupError: unknown encoding: idna`

Comment: On Fedora24, `unicodedata` is provided as part of a `python-libs` package (a distro-specific package, not a pip one). I don't know anything about Python on Windows, but could it be that you either have an incomplete installation of Python, or that some things are in a place where Python is not looking? Check the path it's using with `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'` in a command window perhaps? Is anything else missing?

Comment: `unicodedata` has been a standard module since at least Python 2.2. If `import unicodedata` raises `ImportError` your Python installation is broken.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to import `unicodedata2`?

Then do `import unicode`. It works for me.

Comment: `import unicode` and `import unicodedata2` gives me `ImportError: No module named unicode\unicodedata2`

Comment: @glr this is a comment, not an answer

Comment: I think he means `pip install unicodedata2` and then trying to `import unicode`. Do `pip search unicodedata` and see what it says.

Comment: `pip search unicodedata` and `pip install unicodedata2` both says `LookupError: unknown encoding: idna`

Answer (score 0):

I did not solved this problem with python 2.7.12 and try to install `python 3.6.1`. Now it's working correctly.